# jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm using jquery to drag some divs around, and at the end when i release the div i set it to position fixed and i give it the coordonates event.screenX and event.screenY but this method isn't working as good as i want, the coordonates seem to have some sort of offset and i can't figure out how to get pass this.Could anyone suggest a better solution or a fix? Thanks!

heres a demo http://jsfiddle.net/xtGSL/7/ 
you can see that if moved the box simply jumps out of sight, on a larger page you are still able too see it the offset is around 40px

Comment: can you show us your code until now or create a demo at http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capturing the difference between the element's top left coordinate and the mouse pointer at the start of the dragging operation. At the end, add this difference to the mouse pointer location when setting the position of the element.

You can capture the mouse position like so:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   start: function(event, ui) {
     // here, event.pageX and event.pageY contain the mouse pointer location
   }
});
```

Comment: that fixes the offset problem but now i'm no longer able to move the div more than once http://jsfiddle.net/xtGSL/8/

Comment: @andrei - I think that problem was probably there before? :) Maybe a new question is in order.

Comment: @andrei - what's the purpose of your `stop` function anyway? Just removing that leaves the div where you drop it.

Comment: i use it to store the coords of the box.your comment was useful though, i removed the start and stop completely and now it works just fine.